# PHP Pass user id to mysql trigger

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I need to create a log table and as expected I need to store the user id and the old and new row values.

The thing is that I want to create a trigger to do that to me but I know that is not possible to send parameters to triggers.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another hack: you can use connection based variable `@var`.

sample:

```
  set @user_id = 321
  update table .....
  set @user_id = null;
```

and in update trigger you can use this variable `@user_id`.

Comment: Thanks for you comment but I have no idea on how to do it

Comment: @Gerep, do use use stored procedure or query? You can create SP, encapsulate your update statement into it. And add before it `set @user_id = any_value`. After it, in trigger you can use `@user_id` var. I can post an example but it's trivial.

Comment: I use query and if you can edit your answer with a example it will be great...thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Gerep, please follow the link http://pastebin.com/TqfK3aYA. It is a kind of unit test: create 2 tables, 2 triggers (after insert/update) and a couple of insert/update queries. Insert/update smth in z_test and get results in z_filling_by_trigger. Do not forget about choosing db to run this script (tested in 5.1.19).

Answer (score 1):

Not without some sort of ugly hack - which could be a trigger to think in something else than triggers.

Now for one posiibility of the ugly hack:

Assuming you username can't contain \n, you could do something like

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET <fieldname>=CONCAT('$username','\n','<newvalue>') WHERE <primarykey>=<something>
```

and then let your trigger take off the prepended username and newline. Again: This is an ugly hack.