# How to active the trigger from the script ? PHP AND MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have these two tableS :

table1 :

```
=================
userId | userName
-----------------
   1      name1
   2      name2
   3      name3 
   .        .
   .        .
```

table2 :

```
=========================
businessId | bussinesName
-------------------------
    88          fty
    77          dgre
    .            .
    .            .
```

I want to create another table called history table  , and insert  every query run on table 2.
I am using this trigger :

```
create trigger historyTable after update on table2
for each row insert into historyTable ....
```

my problem I want also to save the userId at historyTable, so now I will know , which user update table2.
so I want to send the userId  from the php script to the Mysql !
How could I do that ?

Comment: I misunderstood the question. That can't be done since there are no input parameters for a trigger.

Comment: check this one it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619614/php-pass-user-id-to-mysql-trigger

Comment: aaa ok ! I instead of using trigger I should implement that on my php script !

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty that is very helpful , so before running the update query on my php script, I should run this query "set /@user_id = 321".

Comment: yes, you need to set that so that for the connection the variable is available and your trigger can see that variable.