# How to add the modified information in a mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, triggers

My database has the following tables:

```
products
product_features
customers
payments
```

There is also an `users` table who can modify, delete or add any item in tables above.
Then I'm trying to store all these actions, and I want to enable or disable products or product_features too (not only deleting). Disabled items would not be accesible by the

So I thought in create a new table called logs with the following fields:

```
id_log
action (delete, update, add)
id_user
table_afected (products, product_features, customers, payments)
id_affected
enabled 
date_added
date_modified
```

Then I'll use mySQL triggers and this way to set the user:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8621168/2154101

Now suppose that I want to save the fields of the id_affected that was being modified. How could I handle that as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save all changes (on each table what fields were modified) then database triggers would be a good approach.

An alternative, more flexible where you can pass parameters is to make manual inserts from the application with all the logic and rules you want

In regards to saving the IDs, that is an easy task. Usually what's done is to have a table (let's call i LOG) that has the fields (TABLE_NAME, FIELD_NAME, OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE, KEY or ID). In this table you save for instance ('USERS', 'FIRSTNAME', 'Johnny', 'John', 234) and you will know someone did an update like
update USERS set FIRSTNAME = 'John' where ID = 234

The columns OLD_VALUE and NEW_VALUE can be of type VARCHAR (or CLOB if they need to support larger data) in order to store any type of field values.

The good thing about the triggers is that they fire if modifications are made from your application and also they will fire if the modification is done directly from the database as a SQL change done by the DBA.

Comment: Ok, I will use triggers. But what about the last question? I've updated the question. Check it out, please.

Comment: I updated my response. See if that answers your question

Comment: thanks! but what would be the type of OLD_VALUE field. Suppose that the user updates a date, and before updates a varchar field, for example.

Comment: It would be a 'catch all' type like VARCHAR or even CLOB to support larger data.

Comment: Then if more than one field is edited I'd have to loop them in the trigger to add each one to the table with OLD_VALUE and NEW_VALUE, true? Well, I like the idea, but I think is little dirty. Are you sure there is no other way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each change would insert a new row.

An alternative, if you 'd like to keep stuff in one row you can use for OLD_VALUE and for the NEW_VALUE a CLOB field and have an XML like

```
<FIELD_VALUES>
    <FIELD1>value1</FIELD1>
    <FIELD2>value2</FIELD2>
    ...
</FIELD_VALUES>
```

ANd then in your app you can parse this XML and even display the log in colors with the field that were modified

As an option here you can save all fields or just the modified ones, whatever you prefer.